# Dll libraries are not refreshing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have strange issue regarding visual studio 2013 after migrate from visual studio 2010 envinorment. It's about when i do some changes to any of my projects and then rebuilt it, my other's projects which have reference to those dlls are not updating. Do you know how to force visual studio 2013 to update all my projects when some of them change its dlls? Somehow vs 2010 did that.

What i did as additional so far:
- was tried to make project order built and dependency (not working)

The only way it can work for me is to delete dll from certain project and make reference once again.. ;/

Answer (score 1):

think i found out the solution - just for those projects which are referencing to libraries projects, after libraries project/s are changed and built it seems if i do Unload on the project/s which are consuming those changed libraries project/s and then reload + rebuild dll's will be updated.

P.S Still looking for more convinient solution